# How to prettify URL based on product from url params with Angular hash included

Tags: angular, redirect, hash, seo, clean-urls

I'll edit this post now since now I know what it is about. I want to have a pretty URL for my website with products.
In my .htaccess file i need to point to www.mydomain.com/site/#?title=orange
from www.mydomain.com/site/orange

I've tried all regex possible in my .htaccess file but it just does not work.
I'm starting to think it is because of the angular # (hash) sign in the URL which is required for my site to work properly.

When I click a product, then my URL changes with this code:

```
        var url = location.href.split('#?')[0] + element;
        window.location.href = url;
        window.location.reload();
```

Then there is a reload and the link is updated to the new URL parameter showing my clicked product.
I just want the www.mydomain.com/site/orange to point at www.mydomain.com/site/#?title=orange (the Hash is needed)

Comment: Google "seo-friendly urls in X" where X is the server-side language you're using.

Comment: I don't know why Google didn't give you this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of ways to do this. The concept is called "clean urls" which basically turns a url like `www.exmaple.com?page=product&slug=Womens-Jackets` into `www.example.com/womens-jackets`

You'll first need your webserver software (Apache, Nginx, etc) to handle the initial rewrite. For Apache you can use .htaccess file to handle this thorugh `mod_rewrite`. [How to use mod_rewrite to create clean URLs](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)

After that your server-side application needs to handle the request parameters - for example `?page=product&slug=Womens-Jackets` - and use that to look up the item in the database to display the correct page/product.

Comment: I host my things on one.com so I have no real power over the server side. But I think I'm able to modify a .htaccess file from there.